# error: conflicting types for 'GetSystemTimeAsFileTime' while building cmake+boost project on mingw64

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, mingw, mingw-w64

Trying to build a C++ project based on CMake and Boost with Mingw64.
I installed cmake and boost msys2-mingw64 packages.
Get this error about conflicting types (`LPFILETIME` vs `FILETIME`) for `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`.

```
$ cmake --build .
[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/...
In file included from ....cpp:1:
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include\boost/thread.hpp:13:
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include\boost/thread/thread.hpp:12:
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include\boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:15:
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include\boost/thread/win32/thread_data.hpp:10:
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include\boost/thread/thread_time.hpp:10:
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include\boost/date_time/microsec_time_clock.hpp:23:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include\boost/date_time/filetime_functions.hpp:57:46: error: conflicting types for 'GetSystemTimeAsFileTime'
        __declspec(dllimport) void __stdcall GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(FILETIME* lpFileTime);
                                             ^
C:\msys64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\sysinfoapi.h:38:26: note: previous declaration is here
  WINBASEAPI VOID WINAPI GetSystemTimeAsFileTime (LPFILETIME lpSystemTimeAsFileTime);
                         ^
```

and many other similar errors.

Bug in mingw64 package? Missing definitions?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out one has to define `BOOST_USE_WINDOWS_H`.

Fix for CMake project:

```
if(WIN32)
    add_definitions(-DBOOST_USE_WINDOWS_H)
endif()
```